# How to Run Laravel Tests with MongoDB Models in Memory with SQLite

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, sqlite, unit-testing

I'm using laravel with MongoDB database. I'm trying to write some tests, but I can't interact with the models when I use `SQLite` to run. It happen because I have to replace the default `Model` class to `MongoDB\Laravel\Eloquent\Model`. So when I try to create a model in the test, nothing happen in the database. Example:

In `Product.php`

```php
use MongoDB\Laravel\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';

    protected $guarded = [
    ];
}
```

In `ProductTest.php`

```php
class ProductTest extends TestCase

{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    public function test_if_product_can_be_created()
    {
        Product::create([
            'uuid' => '1234',
        ]);

        // Failed asserting that table [products] matches expected entries count of 1. Entries found: 0.

        $this->assertDatabaseCount('owners', 1);
    }
}
```

So, how can I run tests in memory since I can't use SQLite? Is there a way to handle this?